# Rails: How to test a controller with routes defined via a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, functional-testing

Given the route:

```
  scope :path => 'shipping_reports', :controller => 'ShippingReports', :as => 'shipping_reports' do
    get 'index'
  end
```

and the following tests:

```
class ShippingReportsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 test "routing" do
    assert_routing '/shipping_reports/index', { :controller => "ShippingReports", :action => "index" }
  end

  test 'index' do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
 end
end
```

First test passes, second fails with:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"shipping_reports"}
```

Anybody has an idea how I can make that test pass?

Comment: I found that the 'index' test worked if the 'routing' test was removed. I can't see why that would be an issue myself! I'll update the post if I find out why ...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to make this work is to change my routes to:

```
controller 'shipping_reports', :path => '/shipping_reports', :as => 'shipping_reports'
```

it reads nicer and tests pass but I still wonder how to test the question routes...

Comment: Hi, I'm running into the exact same issue...have you found an answer to your original problem?  Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry @AL, since the above answer is actually better, I stopped looking for an answer. I wasted a lot of time on it already :(

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar problem.

Given the route:

```
  scope ":client" do
    resources :categories, as: :client_categories
  end
```

I had to do the following:

```
test '#update' do
  put :update, { params: { id: cat.id, client: client } } # => error
  put :update, { params: { id: cat.id, } }, { client: client } # => OK
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. What I did was to the rails predefined path on the test route.

See the test modification below

```
class ShippingReportsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 test "routing" do
    assert_routing index_path, { :controller => "ShippingReports", :action => "index" }
  end

  test 'index' do
    get index_path #the actual path to the index controller
    assert_response :success
 end
end
```

N:B You can get the path name on the route list on localhost `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes`